# Sticky order review section woocommerce

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, woocommerce, sticky

Im having a bit of trouble getting the review order (in this case enquiry) section to stick to the bottom of the header on scroll.

Ive gone through a few jquery examples with no luck and am now playing around with the sticky position for the element. Using a codepen example and playing around with it ive got it to work alright and have tried replicating it on the page through the inspector with no luck.

**Codepen example**

HTML

```
<main class="main-container">
  <header class="main-header">HEADER</header>
  <div class="main-content">MAIN CONTENT</div>
  <div class="second-content">SECOND CONTENT</div> 
  <footer class="main-footer">FOOTER</footer>
</main>
```

CSS

```
body{color:#fff; font-family:arial; font-weight:bold; font-size:40px; }
.main-container{ max-width:1000px; margin:0 auto; border:solid 10px green; padding:10px; margin-top:40px;}
.main-container *{padding:10px;background:#aaa; border:dashed 5px #000;}
.main-container * + *{margin-top:20px;}
.main-header{
  height:50px; background:#aaa; border-color:red;
}
.main-content{
    display:inline-block;
    width:49%;
    height:900px;
}

.second-content{
  display:inline;
  width: 49%;
  height: 200px;
  position: sticky;
  top:0;
}
```

https://codepen.io/elad2412/pen/QYLEdK

**Website URL**
https://trolleys.wpengine.com/

Based on my understanding you would need jQuery to stop it from going through the footer as well correct?

Ive tried going about this a few different ways and tried it on a few different elements, some of which have stuck for a little while but i need to catch the whole column.

This is an example that best shows what im after, tried implementing this but couldnt get it working.
http://jsfiddle.net/bryanjamesross/VtPcm/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed,

Had to give the form a few extra attributes, i was applying them to an outer div.

```
form.checkout {
    height: 1500px;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
}
```